# Ambiguous overload in gcc, fine with msvc

Tags: c++, templates

The following code compiles fine with msvc 18.00 but fails with gcc 4.9.1:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int N> class Num { };

class Zero { };

template <int N, int M>
Num<N + M> operator+(Num<N>, Num<M>)
{
  return {};
}

template <int N>
Zero operator+(Num<N>, Num<-N>)
{
  return {};
}

int main()
{
  Num<1> one;
  Num<-1> mone;
  Num<0> null;

  auto a = one + one;
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a), Num<2>>::value, ":(");

  auto b = one + mone;
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(b), Zero>::value, ":(");

  auto c = null + null;
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(c), Zero>::value, ":(");
}
```

gcc's error message is:

```
ambiguous.cpp: In function 'int main()':
ambiguous.cpp:28:16: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Num<1>' and 'Num<-1>')
   auto b = one + mone;
                ^
ambiguous.cpp:28:16: note: candidates are:
ambiguous.cpp:8:12: note: Num<(N + M)> operator+(Num<N>, Num<M>) [with int N = 1; int M = -1]
 Num<N + M> operator+(Num<N>, Num<M>)
            ^
ambiguous.cpp:14:6: note: Zero operator+(Num<N>, Num<(- N)>) [with int N = 1]
 Zero operator+(Num<N>, Num<-N>)
      ^
ambiguous.cpp:29:47: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(b), Zero>::value, ":(");
                                               ^
ambiguous.cpp:31:17: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Num<0>' and 'Num<0>')
   auto c = null + null;
                 ^
ambiguous.cpp:31:17: note: candidates are:
ambiguous.cpp:8:12: note: Num<(N + M)> operator+(Num<N>, Num<M>) [with int N = 0; int M = 0]
 Num<N + M> operator+(Num<N>, Num<M>)
            ^
ambiguous.cpp:14:6: note: Zero operator+(Num<N>, Num<(- N)>) [with int N = 0]
 Zero operator+(Num<N>, Num<-N>)
      ^
ambiguous.cpp:32:47: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(c), Zero>::value, ":(");
                                               ^
```

Which compiler is right?

Comment: Not an answer, but you could get rid of this ambiguity by getting rid of the second overload and changing `Zero` to `using Zero = Num<0>;`

Comment: @TartanLlama this is just toy code to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to say this, but MSVC is right and [gcc 5.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd7dd3ef7958315b) and [clang 3.6](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3fbcb9d4c28a4f0) are wrong! To simplify, we're calling:

```
operator+(Num<1>, Num<-1>)
```

with overloads:

```
operator+(Num<N>, Num<M>)
operator+(Num<N>, Num<-N>)
```

Both are obviously viable candidates. And, according to [over.match.best]:

> Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>   `F2` if for all arguments `i`, ICS<sub>*i*</sub>(`F1`) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICS<sub>*i*</sub>(`F2`), and then
>
> - [...]
> - `F1` and `F2` are function template specializations, and the function template for `F1` is more specialized
>     than the template for `F2` according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.

The rules for determining partial ordering boil down to: for every template parameter, synthesize a new type/value and try to call the other overload with it. For the first overload, it becomes `operator+(Num<A>, Num<B>)`, with which you cannot call `operator+(Num<N>, Num<-N>)`. However, the second overload becomes `operator+(Num<C>, Num<-C>)`, with which you *can* call the first overload.

Thus, the overload taking `Num<-N>` is more specialized than the overload taking `Num<M>`, so it should be preferred unambiguously.